# Keep getting the error "unhashable type: 'Series' " when trying to retrieve certain data and corresponding numbers in a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, file, statistics

So I'm importing and reading a CSV (Excel) file to gather the mean and standard deviation of certain criteria.Here is the code that I've generated to open it and read it as well as it's corresponding shape.

```
data=pd.read_csv("Factors_Monthly.csv")
shape_data=(data.shape)
print("Data Shape:",shape_data)
```

I want to find the standard deviation of certain numbers in a specific year (1964) and when I try to run the code which is :

```
d2=data.loc(data['year']==1964) #locating all the data of the year 1964
s3=statistics.stdev(d2['smb']) #using the stats library to find the sd of smb in 1964
```

it returns the error "unhashable type: 'Series'" which is unexpected since I was able to calculate the mean of a column in the file with this code with no issues:

```
s1 = statistics.mean(data['rf']) #this is taking the mean of the column rf in the excel file
print(s1)
```

EDIT: (Traceback)
[image]

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: Are you sure you want `data.loc` and not `d2 = data[data['year'] == 1964]`?

Answer (score 1):

Change `d2=data.loc(data['year']==1964)` to `d2=data.loc[data['year']==1964]` and try it.  Parens to bracket.  `loc()` to `loc[]`